# jquery adjust size div with text inside div container resizable

Tags: jquery

I have a `<div>` container resizable (`#extern`) and another `<div>` inside (`#intern`) with text.
When I resize `#extern` I resize `#intern`, but I would like that #intern is not smaller than the text.
I thought to calculate the width of the words (by adding a span) and then calculate the height, but I do not know how to do because computation of the measures is not correct.
I must also take into account the size of the font that can change.
I hope I explained.
I have to finish a job and I'm going crazy, any help will be greatly appreaciated!

I am attaching an img of what I get when I resize: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/wsao.png/.
thanks

Example a part of Code http://jsfiddle.net/6L32g/

Comment: can you post the code? Your explanation is difficult to understand

Comment: Yes, I post here http://jsfiddle.net/6L32g/

Answer (score 0):

Capture the length and width of the div as it is being resized, and input those parameters into a calculation which changes the font size of `div#intern`.  You should place a lower limit on how small the length and width of the container div can be.  Play around with different scaling values to make a formula which yields a corresponding font size which works.

If you are using jQuery UI, then trigger the calculation on the `resize()` event for your implementation of Resizable.

Comment: I have no problem to get the size of the div resizes, but I have problems to adjust these dimensions to the text content.
I have attached the code and an image of what I get when I resize.
thanks